# How to filter appRoleAssignments in Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have an enterprise application in our Azure AD tenant, and I would like to check if a specific group is assigned to this application or not.

To list all appRoleAssignments for the application I can do this:

`GET /beta/servicePrincipals/{id}/appRoleAssignments`

where `{id}` is the ID of the enterprise application. This returns a list of [appRoleAssignment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/approleassignment?view=graph-rest-beta) objects. I would like to filter this list on a specific group as the list can potentially be quite large. I have tried to use the `$filter` query parameter, but I can't seem to get that working. I have tried the following:

`$filter=principalId eq '{groupId}'`

which does not work. I'm getting this error message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadRequest",
        "message": "Invalid filter clause",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "<id>",
            "date": "<date>"
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to filter the list?

I can potentially do this the other way around, by fetching all appRoleAssignments the group is assigned to, by doing the following request:

`GET /beta/groups/{groupId}/appRoleAssignments`

but I seem to be having the same issue here, there is no way to use `$filter` to filter on the specific enterprise application I want to check for.

If filtering does not work, is there any other endpoint I can use so I won't have to do pagination in the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible.

The confusion here is caused by the fact that in Microsoft Graph beta, the `principalId` and `resourceId` properties of an `AppRoleAssignment` entity are declared as `Edm.Guid`, rather than the more familiar `Edm.String`.

#### Using Microsoft Graph beta

To retrieve all app role assignments for a given group, to a given resource app, using Microsoft Graph API (with newlines for legibility):

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{group-id}/appRoleAssignments
        ?$filter=resourceId eq {resource-id}
```

Where:

- `{group-id}` is the group's object ID
- `{resource-id}` is the service principal object ID of the resource app

> **Important**: Note the absence of single quotes (`'`) surrounding `{resource-id}`. This is required when the attribute being filtered on is of type `Edm.Guid`.

With sample values, this query look like this:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/75c647eb-8ff0-478d-b131-6c1bd4071841/appRoleAssignments
        ?$filter=resourceId eq ddd57b26-e13e-4db4-93d3-996f382251df
```

---

I'd also like to take the opportunity to clarify a possible confusion I noticed in the question. Using Microsoft Graph beta:

- The `appRoleAssignments` navigation on users, groups and service principals will return the app role assignments which the user, group or service principal has been granted (i.e. where the user/group/service principal is the `principalId` of the returned `AppRoleAssignment`).
- The `appRoleAssignedTo` navigation on a service principal will return the app role assignments where the service principal in question is the resource app exposing the app role (i.e. where the service principal is the `resourceId` of the returnd `AppRoleAssignment`).

#### Using Azure AD Graph 1.6

> **Note**: In general, the recommendation is to use Microsoft Graph. Only use  Azure AD Graph if the capability is not available on Microsoft Graph v1.0 and you require a production-ready API. You should plan to move to Microsoft Graph as soon as the capability is made available in v1.0.

To retrieve all app role assignments for a given group, to a given resource app, using Azure AD Graph API (with newlines for legibility):

```
GET https://graph.windows.net/{tenant-id}/groups/{group-id}/appRoleAssignments
        ?$filter=resourceId eq guid'{resource-sp-id}'
        &api-version=1.6
```

Where:

- `{tenant-id}` is the tenant ID or a verified domain name
- `{group-id}` is the group's object ID
- `{resource-sp-id}` is the service principal object ID of the resource app

Comment: I was pretty sure I had tried without the quotes as well in the filter clause, but apparently not. Thanks!

I'm also somewhat confused that `$filter eq ' ... '` does not always work on properties that the docs say is a string, but that is a different question I guess.

Comment: Not all properties can be filtered on. Strings that _can_ be filtered on require the use of single quotes. Guids require the single quotes be omitted.

Comment: Is there anywhere in the docs that say which attributes can be filtered on? Or perhaps in a schema?

Comment: Today, this should be included in the API documentation for each resource type. (E.g. 'Supports $filter in [user properties list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties). If you don't see this for a resource type, you can open an issue at the bottom of the documentation page.) Unfortunately, this information is not (yet) contained in the metadata annotations (the `FilterRestrictions` annotations says if the entity is filterable, but does not go into details for which attributes support which filters).

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret How is that possible with Graph API for C#? Filter($"resourceId eq guid'{servicePrincipal.Id}'") --> does not work. Filter($"resourceId eq {servicePrincipal.Id}") --> also does not work.

Answer (score 0):

`principalId`  does not support `$filter`.

Reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/approleassignment?view=graph-rest-1.0).

[image]